# Writing a function that copies a string literal into a char array given by a pointer

Tags: c++, string, dynamic, copy

This is for a part of a class project. It's not required, but right now I'm assigning characters one at a time, and it adds dozens of lines to my code. I would like to write a function that would take a string literal and a pointer, and copy the literal into the array being pointed to.

It would look something like this.

```
char* word = new char[12];
stringCopy(word, "thisisaword");
cout << word;
```

The program would print "thisisaword" to the screen.

Because this is for a class, I'm limited in what I can do.

--I have to dynamically allocate and size arrays exactly (by using temporary, unsized arrays and finding their length to allocate exactly-sized new ones)

--I can't use any string library functions, I must write my own

--I can't use overloaded operators

So far, I haven't tried anything to implement this, because I don't know how. I have written a function that does this given two pointers, which is so simple I need not post its code. strlen the source, delete and then allocate the right amount to the destination pointer, then copy char-by-char in a loop controlled by the string length.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Bad class. `std::string` should be taught from day 1. As an advanced course, one could look into the details, but the basic course should focus on not reinventing the wheel. We have far too many programmers who can reinvent wheels and too few who can use the existing.

Comment: I think the "invent your own string" is to show about why copy constructors are needed, how to overload operators etc.

Comment: No overloaded operators allowed either.

Comment: Also, the focus on these courses is to teach us problem solving more than the actual code. They want us to write everything ourselves and limit what we can use so that we can learn to solve problems while fitting into certain constraints, which is a huge part of real-world programming. Once we get into upper-level courses, they give us much more freedom.

Comment: @user1362548 By that logic, you should be soldering transistors together rather than using C++. This isn’t an attack on you but rather the course – it’s well established that this way of teaching is wrong, wrong, wrong.

Comment: So... can anyone actually answer the question?

Comment: I don't understand. The question says that you don't know how to do this, but then that you implemented this already and that it's so simple that you don't need to post the code? I'm confused as hell.

Comment: @user1362548: Fair enough, but if it's supposed to teach you how to manage memory, then it should focus on [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) not pointer-juggling. If you have a dumb pointer to dynamic memory, then you're well on the way to memory leaks and worse.

Comment: I don't understand a lot of the negative replies. To have good command of the language, you need to be aware of what's happening under the hood. Everyone has their way of teaching and learning too, though. To be fair though, this assignment may as well be done in pure C.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I like that logic. If I was teaching computer courses I *would* start with a 4-bit adder built in transistors. Then move up to assembly language before ever touching C.

Answer (score 1):

I love these task. Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>

struct P { char const* s; std::size_t z; };
template <std::size_t z>
P s(char const(&s)[z]) { return { s, z }; }

int main()
{
    auto p(s("thisisaword"));
    char* word = new char[p.z];
    for (auto i(0);  (i<:word:> = i<:p.s:>); ++i) <%%>
    std::cout << word << '\n';
    delete[] word;
}
```

Comment: We can't use overloaded operators.

Comment: @user1362548: that's a shame. I change to the code use something different then.

Comment: Was there a reason for using crazy looking digraph tokens that hardly anyone knows exist? :-)

Comment: I think the for loop looks a lot better using digraphs. Of course, there isn't any particular reason to use them other than this solution doing the right thing but hardly being acceptable to solve the homework assignment. ... and, no, there is also no reason to write the array subscripts the way they are written other than exploiting a language oddity.